# Finding $\inf(S)$ and $\sup(S)$ for $S = \{\frac{(m+n)^2}{2^{mn}} : m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Given a set S such that $S = \{\frac{(m+n)^2}{2^{mn}} : m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, what is $\sup{S}$ and what is $\inf{S}$?

I think $\inf{S}$ is 0 because if we let $n = m$ and allow $m$ to approach infinity, the limit is 0, and clearly no element of $S$ can be negative. However, I am not sure how to find the supremum, except

Comment: try looking at what happens to $S_{m,n}$ as you send $n \to n+1$.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Do you mean to see what happens when I fix m and increment n? It looks like the denominator gains a power of $2^m$ with each increment of n, while the squared value in the numerator increases by 1

Comment: Exactly, I'll write the point I'm making as an answer

Comment: One of the characteristics of $\mathbb N$ is that it has a least element.  I will wager a nickle that $\sup(S(m,n))$ appears when m,n are somewhere near their least element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that if you increase $n$ (or equivalently $m$) by $1$, we have 
$$\frac{\frac{(m+n+1)^{2}}{2^{m(n+1)}}}{\frac{(m+n)^{2}}{2^{mn}}}=\left(1+\frac{1}{m+n}\right)^{2}\frac{1}{2^{m}}$$
If this is less than $1$ (and it is if $m$ or $n$ is at least $2$), then we lose by making $m$ or $n$ any bigger. This leaves a limited number of cases to check.

Comment: Great! It looks like the supremum is 9/4, based on that reasoning

Answer (score 0):

Except  for $(2,2)$ the $S$ is less than $1$ that's the reason why limit approaches to $0$ after equalizing $m,n$.So sup(S)=1

Comment: Isn't the value for m=1 and n=2 equal to 9/4, which is greater than 1?